# Remove Image from memory in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, image

Befor uploading Images to Server I want to get the size, height and width of Images. To do it, I use FileReader.

```
function getImageInfo(i) {
var f = files[i];
var oFReader = new window.FileReader();
oFReader.readAsDataURL(f);
oFReader.onload = function (oFrEvent) {
    var res = oFrEvent.target.result;
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function () {
        imgList.push({ size: f.size, name: f.name, width: img.width, height: img.height });
        img = null;
        i++;
        if (i < files.length) {
            getImageInfo(i);
        } else {
            showImages();
        }
    };
    img.src = res;
};
```

}

I tried to open over 30 Pictures, size > 3 MB.
 After ca. 20 Pictures i get:

*JavaScript runtime error: Not enough storage is available to complete this operation*.

How to remove img from storage?
 img setting to null; does not help.

Best regards and thanks

Comment: What browser are you using? Do you get this runtime error message in different browsers?

Comment: I've tested in Chrome, Mozilla, IE 11 and Edge. It look so, that only in IE11 exists this problem.
In IE 11 by ca. 100 MB is over. In all other I tried until 500 MB and it was OK